# How to set request_id in Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some code that relies on `request_id` being set, but when testing in RSpec 3.8 and Rails 5.1 `request_id` is not set. It works in development and production.

I have tried setting the `X-Request-Id` header manually in the spec file, but it does not work.

I am not sure if it is a Rails issue in the test environment or whether it is caused by RSpec.

In my spec:

```rb
request.headers.add('X-Request-Id', SecureRandom.uuid)
patch model_update_path(model), params: { model: { attr: 'changed' }}
... # actual tests
```

and in my controller

```rb
...
def update
  logger.info "Request Id: #{request.request_id}"
  logger.info "X-Request-Id: #{request.header['X-Request-Id']}"
  ... # actual logic
end
...
```

The first line logs nothing, while the second logs the random uuid.

I expected the `request.request_id` method to return a unique uuid for each request in the test environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
patch model_update_path(model), { params: { model: { attr: 'changed' }, 'X-Request-Id' => SecureRandom.uuid }
```

Comment: The syntax is invalid; `patch` expects a path followed by `**args` which cannot be both a hash (as indicated by `params: {...}` and a list as indicated by the unnamed `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could stub the method `request_id` of all instances from the class `ActionController::TestRequest`:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ActionController::TestRequest).to receive(:request_id).and_return(SecureRandom.uuid)
patch model_update_path(model), params: { model: { attr: 'changed' }}
```